# How I can draw a line between any two points on a graphed function?

Tags: algorithm, line, newline, gnuplot

I want draw a line between two any points (know and unknown) that are in a previous graph in gnplot, how can I do that?

Comment: You want to draw to an **unknown** point? Please, clearify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
set arrow from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2 nohead
```

And of course, you can specify the color and line type and style as well by adding `linecolor` (`lc`), `linetype` (`lt`) and `linestyle` (`ls`).  e.g:

```
set arrow from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2 lc rgb "green" nohead
```

or

```
set arrow from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2 lc rgb "#00ff00" nohead
```

It's a bit hard to say what you want when you say that you want to draw an arrow to an *unknown* point.  Perhaps it is some feature in the datafile that you want.  If that's the case, you might be able to pick it up using `stats`:

```
stats 'datafile' u 1:2
set arrow from X1,Y1 to STATS_pos_min_x,STATS_min_y nohead
```

This will plot a line from whatever you define X1,Y1 to be to the point on the plot of minimal y.